# HTML not getting changed after jQuery call is made successfully

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a voting mechanism on the site. When people vote up or down, this code is called:

```
// Called right away after someone clicks on the vote up link
$('.vote_up').click(function() 
{    

var problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");

queue.voteUp = $(this).attr('problem_id'); 

var span = $(this).closest('span').find('span.votes');

queue.span = span;

vote(problem_id , 1);

//Return false to prevent page navigation
return false;       
});
```

and the vote function that it calls looks like this:

```
var vote = function(problem_id , vote) 
{
    if ( vote == 1 )
    {
        queue.voteUp = problem_id;
    }
    else
    if ( vote == -1 )
    {
        queue.voteDown = problem_id;
    }   

    var dataString = 'problem_id=' + problem_id + '&vote=' + vote;

// The person is actually logged in so lets have him vote
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/problems/vote.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data)
                {                               
                    text = queue.span.text ();

                    if ( vote == -1 )
                    {
                        if ( data == "update_success" )
                        {
                            incrementedText = parseInt(text ,10) - 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            incrementedText = parseInt(text ,10) - 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    if ( vote == 1 )
                    {
                        if ( data == "update_success" )
                        {
                            incrementedText = parseInt(text ,10) + 2;
                        }
                        else                    
                        {
                            incrementedText = parseInt(text ,10) + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    queue.span.text(incrementedText + " ");
                },
                error : function(data) 
                {
                    errorMessage = data.responseText;

                    if ( errorMessage == "not_logged_in" )
                    {
                        queue.login = false;

                        //set the current problem id to the one within the dialog
                        $problemId.val(problem_id);                 

                        // Try to create the popup that asks user to log in.
                        //  $dialog.dialog('open');
                        $("#loginpopup").dialog();

                        errorMessage = "";

                        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    if ( errorMessage == "already_voted" )
                    {
                        // Display a dialog box saying that the user already voted
                        $('<div />').html('You already voted this way on this problem.').dialog();
                    }
                    else
                    if (  errorMessage == "error_getting_vote" )
                    {

                        $('<div />').html('Error getting existing votes.').dialog();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // ? :)
                    }    
                } // End of error case  
            }); // Closing AJAX call.
    };
```

and here is the PHP that made the HTML for the vote button.  The link is called "important" or "not important" :

```
echo '<span class="half_text" style="color: #B77F37;">'.$problem_date.'</span>
<span id="votes" class="half_text" style="padding-left: 10px;">'.$vote.'</span>
<strong> <a class="vote_up" style="font-size: 80.0%; color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;" href="#" data-problem_id="'.$problem_id.'">Important</a></strong>
|
<strong><a class="vote_down" style="font-size: 80.0%; color: #295B7B; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;" href="#" data-problem_id="'.$problem_id.'">Not Important</a></strong>';
```

When a user votes, the AJAX gets called, and everything works ok.  The only problem is that the HTML does not get updated with the new vote count.  Any idea how I can accomplish that?

Comment: are you saying that `queue.span.text(incrementedText + " ")` is not working? Have you put in alerts to verify that "text" is getting the old value and "incrementedText" is getting the new value set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript you attempt to select the `<span id="votes">` using the `votes` class (`$(this).closest('span').find('span.votes');`). So I recommend changing:

```
<span id="votes" class="half_text" style="padding-left: 10px;">
```

To:

```
<span class="votes half_text" style="padding-left: 10px;">
```

I recommend using a parent element to make your selector work properly:

```
$('.vote_up').click(function() {
   console.log($(this).parents('div:first').children('.votes'));
});
//this requires there to be a div element that is the ancestor of the code you posted
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/DzZCY/1/

Comment: are yo allowed to have 2 class attributes in one element?

Comment: @GeekedOut, yeah you just need to do `class="votes half_text"` instead of `class="votes" class="half_text"`